# How to assign vbScript variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to set a vbScript variable (accessOK, which is defined in another file) depending on the case within `jQuery` code. Not sure of the syntax and working with someone else's code also.

The new window should open depending on the level selection.

Problem: Access gets blocked because `accessOK` doesn't get the assignment of true or false.

**Tried**

Using `'<%=accessOK=true%>'` doesn't do anything and using `<%=accessOK=true%>` without the single qoute says `ReferenceError: True is not defined`

What is wrong in the code? Any help would be appreciated.

```
        $('.click_lower').bind('jqplotDataClick', function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
            if (plotData.level != "Global" && plotData.level != "Area" && plotData.level != "Country")
            '<%=accessOK=false%>'
        else
            '<%=accessOK=true%>'
            window.open("index.asp?level="+plotData.detLevel+"&loc="+data[3],'_self' );
    });
```

Comment: You talking about setting a client-side variable to a server-side value? In which case the client-side has to have something to set the value to, remember server-side processing happens before the page is returned. Depending on what you are trying to do try something like this replace `'<%=accessOK=false%>'` with `accessOK = <%= (accessOK = False) %>`;` that should give you a valid line by JavaScript will likely not like the boolean as `True` or `False`, it will be expecting `true` or `false`. So try `accessOK = <%= LCase((accessOK = False)) %>;` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you actually want, something like this should work;

```js
$('.click_lower').bind('jqplotDataClick', function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
  var accessOK;
  if (plotData.level != "Global" && plotData.level != "Area" && plotData.level != "Country") {
    accessOK = <%= LCase((accessOK = False))%>;
  } else {
    accessOK = <%= LCase((accessOK = True))%>;
    window.open("index.asp?level="+plotData.detLevel+"&loc="+data[3],'_self' );
  }
});
```

Just remember that server-side code happens before the page is returned to the client, so the code

```vb
<%= LCase((accessOK = False))%>
```

depending on the server-side variable `accessOK` will be either `True` or `False`. To make sure we don't break JavaScript syntax we use `LCase()` to correct the case.

So when viewing the actual generated HTML you end up with something like;

```js
$('.click_lower').bind('jqplotDataClick', function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
  var accessOK;
  if (plotData.level != "Global" && plotData.level != "Area" && plotData.level != "Country") {
    accessOK = true;
  } else {
    accessOK = false;
    window.open("index.asp?level="+plotData.detLevel+"&loc="+data[3],'_self' );
  }
});
```

Comment: I understand what you suggested, but this code didn't work and still cannot set accessOK=true hence `window.open(...)` does not get accessed

Comment: The problem here @sharlene is you quite clearly have an concept in mind, unfortunately I'm not a mind reader. As your code stands *(even with my modifications)* I don't see what the variable `accessOK` in your client-side code is doing? Remember `var accessOK;` and `<%= accessOK %>` are completely different variables don't confuse them. Where are you checking the value of `accessOK` to affect the `window.open()` call?

Comment: I check the value of accessOK in an `.html` file with integrated `vbScript` code. But that is for clientside check for an option where user selectes something from a menu. But what I am trying to do in the jQuery part is that clicking on a bar of a chart should check the access and open page. On the html side pseudocode follows "if accessOK=true then carry on display else block it"

Comment: @sharlene It's going to hard to answer that with the little bit of code you have posted. The question was *"What's wrong in the code?"* which was you weren't assigning a client-side variable correctly to the server-side variable. The fact it doesn't do what you expect it likely due to other logic in your application. You can test the variable is set right using `alert(accessOK);` after the `if` statement block.

Comment: Well the issue is that the assignemnt is incorrect. accessOK doesn't get set to `true`. Thanks for elaborating.

Comment: @sharlene If you are talking about your server-side `accessOK` variable then consider this, if you don't assign it anything just declare it `Dim accessOK` near top of the page, the code above will default to `False` when compared, but if for example you assign anything other then a `Boolean` for example `accessOK = ""` you will get a `False` comparison every-time.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Assignment actually worked. THe problem was in the URL for the page to open. Sorted  now. Thanks again.

Comment: @sharlene "I check the value of accessOK in an `.html` file with integrated vbScript code."  Unless you have some very unorthodox mappings server side vbs won't work in a file with the html extension, it would need to be a `.asp` file

Comment: @John yes I understand. I have the .asp file which is doing all the work. .html file only does some client side validation. Here was the accessOK clientside and server side confusion.